# How can i load my twitter page using prettyphoto jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/dhirvikram/?iframes=true&width=100%&height=100%" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" title="My Twitter updates">My stuff</a>
```

> When i click on link , it should open a prettyphoto lightbox window with my twitter content.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Twitter has [disabled loading of their pages in `iframes`](http://dsandler.org/outgoing/dontclick_orig.html) (which the plugin you mention uses), so using that plugin to load your Twitter page in an `iframe` won't work.  I'd recommend using Twitter's API to accomplish what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help... can you please tell me how can i use twitter API for my page..